# Rails: has_many WITHOUT belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

I am working with RoR at the moment following some books and tutorials and it works quite well. But now I have to implement something for which I do not find any resource and I need a little help with that. Here's what I want to do:
I have an application where people can log into and view things, so I have a database table called **users**, pretty self-explanatory. Additionally I have a table **user_rights**, each with an id, a name, and a description.
The idea is now, that each user can have multiple rights, giving him access to different parts of the application. Thus:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :password_digest, :password, :account_nr, :password_confirmation, :email
  has_many :scope
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :account_nr, presence: true
  validates :email, :presence => true
  has_secure_password
end
```

and:

```
class Scope < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description
end
```

I do **not** want to have a **belongs_to**-relationship. I just want a small table with user rights and give each user a couple of them. But unfortunately, I have absolutely no idea how to proceed! Could anyone give me some hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you need [many-to-many](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many) association, like: user could have several rights and one right could be assigned to many users.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thanks, that's enough to keep me going!

Comment: Also see the section on RailsGuides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're trying to do is called **authorization** (which you may already know). If you're writing a custom solution, I think there's probably a good chance you're reinventing the wheel.

I would recommend spending some time with [CanCan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan), a Rails authorization plugin written by the RailsCasts guy, to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Hey! I am indeed reinventing the wheel, but I guess that's necessary to learn. Thanks for the link, I will check that out, but I will try to do it without the plugin first so I can learn how everything works :)